# Commerce PaymentGateway configuration

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, payment-methods, omnipay

So I made an account with MultiSafePay:

1. Added my website where i need to get payments from.
2. Filled in the API key and Locale
3. Enabled it for customers (me)
4. Changed the Gateway of MultiSafepay from XmlGateway to RestGateway.
   (Because XMLGateway is deprecated)

How would I add it to the checkout process in Craft Commerce?

Now I only get to see the credit card fields if MultiSafePay is selected in the dropdown, but I enabled all the payment options at MultiSafePay.

Could somebody explain to me and others how to implement it correctly?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'Changed the Gateway of MultiSafepay from XmlGateway to RestGateway. (Because XMLGateway is depricated)'?

Comment: I already have set the XMLGateway to RESTGateway, now it is properly used. But in the checkout i still get creditcard fields instead of a redirect for the payment.

How would i implement such a thing in Craft Commerce?

Comment: Sorry, where have you set that? I see no option within Craft's MultiSafepay gateway.

Comment: class Gateway extends XmlGateway renamed it to
class Gateway extends RestGateway. (because it exists for MultiSafePay)

Comment: Might be worth checking with Craft support that the RestGateway is working. I see what you see, the RestGateway is represented within the code, but it doesn't look finished in terms of integration with Craft Commerce. I'd expect there to be an option when selecting the payment gateway within the admin area if it were working already.

Comment: @ClivePortman yes indeed, i would recommend not to show it at all if it's not implemented. Now it would be selectable, but you still need to type your own plugin to make it work. So it's not an out-of-the-box solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Craft Commerce 1.2.1238](https://craftcommerce.com/changelog#build1328) added support for the REST based Multi-Safepay gateway.